# Update row but leave unchanged some fields

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to update a row, but I would like to leave unchaged a field when there is not a new value to update the field with.

I know I can write a new query, but my table is quite long and I'm looking for an elegant way to do the job.

Let's say that part of my long table is the following:

```
|  id  |   Name   | date_added | date_updated |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1   | Review_1 | 2012-02-10 | 2012-02-20   |
```

I have a form with a checkbox. I would like that if the user checks the checkbox the field date_updated is updated with the current date. But if the checkbox is not checked the field date_updated if left unchanged.

```
if (isset($_POST['updated'])) { 
    $updated = [today's date];
}
```

At the moment my query is this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE reviews r, filters f SET 
                                             r.title = '$title', 
                                             r.description = '$description',
                                             r.date_updated = '$updated',
                                             r.link_homepage = '$homepage'
                                             [etc.]
                                             [etc.]

            WHERE r.id = '$id' AND f.id = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just leave out the date_updated line if it's not needed. So:

```
$updated = '';
if (isset($_POST['updated'])) { 
    $updated = "r.date_updated = NOW(),";
}
```

and then in the query:

```
...
r.description = '$description',
$updated
r.link_homepage = '$homepage'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just not specify the rows you want left alone in the SET criteria, so build that into your PHP logic so that when generating the query it doesn't include SET criteria for fields you want to have left alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example :

```
$updated = (isset($_POST['updated'])) ? "r.date_updated='[your date]'," : '';

mysql_query("UPDATE reviews r, filters f SET 
                                             r.title = '$title', 
                                             r.description = '$description',
                                             $updated
                                             r.link_homepage = '$homepage'
                                             [etc.]
                                             [etc.]

            WHERE r.id = '$id' AND f.id = '$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to worry about your existing query... From the MySQL docs:

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this
>   and does not update it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create the SQL-query as a string, that you then pass to mysql_query(), you can use a simple if-statement to check whether to update or not.

Something like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE reviews r, filters f SET 
             r.title = '$title', 
             r.description = '$description',";

$sql .= (isset($_POST['updated'])) ? "r.date_updated = '$todaysDate'," : "";

$sql .= " r.date_updated = '$updated',
          r.link_homepage = '$homepage'
          [etc.]";

mysql_query($sql);
```